# Pinitos con Symfony en Codeanywhere

Tags: symfony

Veran, actualmente estoy probando un nuevo programa para desarrollo de paginas web llamado Symfony, para lo cual utilizo el servidor Codeanywhere. Estoy intentando hacer una sencilla página web en la cual paso una frase como argumento a una vista.
Este es el código:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me sale este mensaje de error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obviamente, este mensaje a mi no me dice nada, por lo que quisiera saber que hice mal.
Por cierto, utilizo la versión 3. Se que actualmente la versión actual es la 4, pero los tutoriales que sigo son de la versión 2, y eso me distanciaria demasiado.

Edito: Actualmente tengo esta vista:

```
<center>
  <h1>
    ¡Vamos! ¿Queréis ganar o no?
  </h1>
</center>
```

Y he modificado la función indexAction para que la use:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/nuevo.html.twig');
}
```

Y esto sí que me funciona.
Es decir, el fallo no esta en la vista ni en el return.
Tiene que estar en la dirección web.
Tambien he probado esto:

```
/**
 * @Route("/entrena", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request){
    // replace this example code with whatever you need
    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig'
      ,['base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),]);
}
```

Y esto si que falla.

Más datos:
He visitado la carpeta var/logs, donde tengo los informes de errores. En ella 2 ficheros me han llamado la atención.
El primero es "dev.log", en el cual he visto este mensaje de error:

```
[2018-10-01 08:37:48] request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction","token":"c867c1","_route":"_wdt"},"request_uri":"http://empresa-algarroba78565438.codeanyapp.com/web/app_dev.php/_wdt/c867c1"} []
```

El segundo es "prod.log", en el cual el mensaje de error más reciente es el siguiente:

```
[2018-10-01 08:40:07] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /entrena"" at /home/cabox/workspace/var/cache/prod/classes.php line 2383 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /entrena\" at /home/cabox/workspace/var/cache/prod/classes.php:2383, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/cabox/workspace/var/cache/prod/appProdUrlMatcher.php:44)"} []
```

¿Alguien sabe que significa cada error?

Comment: El nombre de la función a la que responde un controlador debe acabar por `Action`. En tu caso debería ser `entrenarAction`

Comment: @Jakala Pues así he hecho pero no ha funcionado. Ademas, tengo una función llamada basado "basado" que a pesar de no tener "Action" funciona, y de hecho, al añadirlo ha dado un error tipo "500 Internal Server Error".

Comment: Entonces echa un vistazo a los archivos de log. En app/logs puedes encontrar más información. En caso de un 500 revisa los de apache/nginx/ o la consola.puede haber más info para ver el error

Comment: @Jakala En el caso de mi versión debo buscar en var/logs. Editare mi pregunta para explicar que he visto.

Comment: @Jakala Listo, ya he editado mi pregunta añadiendo los informes.

Comment: Por lo que veo tienes configurado el entorno en modo prod. Si haces un cambio en las rutas, antes de comprobarlo tienes que limpiar la cache de produccion. Esto lo puedes hacer con el compando `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod`

Comment: @Jakala Pues así fue. Es increible lo delicado que es Symfony.

Comment: la verdad es que para desarrollo se debe trabajar en entorno dev. Con eso la cache se regenera siempre (es mas costoso) pero luego en prod se utiliza la cache y acelera mucho el funcionamiento. Personalmente creo que Symfony es un muy buen framework, te recomendaria que continues con el. Si tienes alguna duda por aqui estaremos :)